# Facebook like post system. Get post data error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 tables post and friends. I want to get all post of my friends but not include block friend from post table. I use all join left, right, inner join but query return all data included block friend data. I want only friend data which is not block like facebook system. My table structure are

**1. post table**

```
|post_id|user_id|content|image|is_delete|created|
-------------------------------------------------
| 1 | 1 | hello | 0 | 0 | 2020-12-23 11:12:11 |
-------------------------------------------------
| 2 | 2 | hi1 | 0 | 0 | 2020-12-24 13:33:42 |
-------------------------------------------------
| 3 | 3 | hi2 | 0 | 0 | 2020-12-24 13:33:42 |
-------------------------------------------------
| 3 | 4 | hi3 | 0 | 0 | 2020-12-24 13:33:42 |
-------------------------------------------------
```

**2. friend table**

```
|id|user_id|request_id|status|block|created|
--------------------------------------------
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 2020-12-23 11:23:23 |
--------------------------------------------
| 1 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 2020-12-23 11:33:33 |
--------------------------------------------
| 1 | 4 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 2020-12-23 11:33:33 |
--------------------------------------------
```

My sql query is

```
select 
    * 
from 
    post p 
left join 
    friends f on (p.user_id = f.user_id or p.user_id = f.request_id) 
where 
    ((f.user_id = '1' OR f.request_id = '1') 
    and f.status = '2' 
    and f.block !=1 
    and p.is_delete !=1)
```

i have change my query to read stackoverflow question and comment but the result is same below

query -

```
select 
    * 
from 
    post p 
left join 
    friends f on (p.user_id = f.user_id or p.user_id = f.request_id) 
    and f.status = '2' and f.block !=1 
where 
    ((f.user_id = '1' OR f.request_id = '1') 
    and p.is_delete !=1)
```

result are

```
|post_id|user_id|content|image|is_delete|created|
-------------------------------------------------
| 1 | 1 | hello | 0 | 0 | 2020-12-23 11:12:11 |
------------------------------------------------
| 2 | 2 | hi1 | 0 | 0 | 2020-12-24 13:33:42 |
------------------------------------------------
| 3 | 3 | hi2 | 0 | 0 | 2020-12-24 13:33:42 |
------------------------------------------------
| 3 | 4 | hi3 | 0 | 0 | 2020-12-24 13:33:42 |
-----------------------------------------------
```

but i want this result

```
|post_id|user_id|content|image|is_delete|created|
-------------------------------------------------
| 1 | 1 | hello | 0 | 0 | 2020-12-23 11:12:11 |
------------------------------------------------
| 3 | 3 | hi2 | 0 | 0 | 2020-12-24 13:33:42 |
------------------------------------------------
| 3 | 4 | hi3 | 0 | 0 | 2020-12-24 13:33:42 |
------------------------------------------------
```

Please tell me what is wrong in my query. Thanks for any help

Comment: You can simply delete the friendship on block.

Comment: I had also worked on similar project, you may visit for getting more ideas.
http://socialcodia.com/famblah
Thanks

Comment: If you want posts by *friends*, why would you want `post_id = 1`?  You question is unclear on what you really want.

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks fine. But Why you are doing the `LEFT JOIN`? It is not needed.

Try following query:

```
select p.* 
from post p 
join friends f on p.user_id in (f.user_id,f.request_id) 
where '1' in (f.user_id,f.request_id) 
    and f.status = '2' 
    and f.block != 1 
    and p.is_delete !=1
```

Answer (score 0):

try :

select p.*
from post p LEFT JOIN friends f on p.user_id = f.user_id
where f.block !=1

This will give you data of friends which are not blocked.
You can add different check if required in where clause.
But this is the simplest solution of your problem requirement i.e. "*I want to get all post of my friends but not include block friend from post table.*"